# Assign 2 actions to one html button

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to assign 2 actions to one `button` in my webpage:

1. send a message to arduino run server
2. change the color of the button with toggleClass so that you can see
   if it's on/off

Code:

```
function autoon() {
    $('#content').load('/arduino/autoon');
    $("button#autoon").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    });      
}
```

Now the color of the buttons change but I need to click the `button` 2 times to change the color.

Comment: can you provide the code in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change your button's class inside the autoon function?

```
$("#autoon").toggleClass("selected");
```

So your autoon function would now become:

```
function autoon()
    {
        $('#content').load('/arduino/autoon');
        $("#autoon").toggleClass("selected");
    }
```